# Replace Black screen/kernel text compiling with image

Tags: boot, kernel, plymouth, configure

Does anyone know of a method or program that allows you no display an image instead of the black screen/compiling text that is normally displayed while booting? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to change that black background color in grub menu.

if so, see it http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/03/how-to-change-grub2-background-image.html